# Django Rest framework except specific column

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to exclude specific column in rest framework only for view data. (not for put data)

[models.py]

```
class article(models.Model):
    articleNo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userkey = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='1234')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

[serializers.py]

```
class articleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = article
        fields = ('articleNo', 'userkey', 'content', 'password', 'date')
```

After I change `fields = ('articleNo', 'content', 'date')` from `serializers.py`,

Only articleNo, content, date will be show in rest framework.

But, When I PUT data to article, It doesn't inserted properly.

After insert data, MySQL data is below.

```
articleNo|content | date                       |userkey    |password    
    37   | Test   | 2018-03-13 08:01:07.424564 |           | 1234
```

userkey is blank and password is default value.

Maybe I have to modify serializers.py I think, But I don't know how to fix it.

How can I insert data properly?

Comment: `PEP8` correct python variable name will be `article_no` and not `articleNo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you cant do that, if you remove any field, that means that field wont be taken while passing from serializer,

instead try this

```
class articleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userkey = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = article
        fields = ('articleNo', 'userkey', 'content', 'password', 'date')
```

Comment: It works exactly what I want! Thanks for quickly reply!!

Comment: glad could help bro :)

Comment: I'm new at Stackoverflow. Accept the answer is click the up arrow button side at your post?

Comment: Ok. I clicked it. Thanks.